# When did husbands & wives start sharing bedrooms?

Tags: social-history, marriage, victorian

In a lot of period movies the husband & wife are shown to be retiring to different bedrooms at night. e.g. most movies about 1800's Britain  or even pre WW-II. Or even War & Peace or Pride & Prejudice. Or The Count of Monte Cristo.

How & when did that change to them sleeping in the same room /  same bed? Was the separate room custom only among the nobles & intelligentsia? Or did the commoners sleep in separate rooms too?

Comment: Hi, welcome to History.SE!

Comment: If you are poor, you can't afford separate beds and bedrooms.

Comment: Your question should probably rather be "When did families start to have dedicated rooms and beds for their children?". In the 19th century there was typically a kitchen/dinning room and a bedroom for the whole family (6 kids was common) (immagine the smell in the morning), exept within the riches of course.

Comment: The question implies that all couples (or most) these days share bedrooms. In all cultures/countries/regions. I'm not sure that this is true.

Comment: @jamesqf My bad. I didn't mean movies made in 1800s. I meant portraying or set in the 1800's or using literature written in the 1800's

Comment: @ypercube Most western cultures do, right? Or are there western cultures where it is still common for a couple to sleep in separate rooms / beds.

Comment: @curious_cat I have personal knowledge (anecdotical, I admit it) of some matures couple that prefer not to share bed out of commodity, and use some of the (previously unused) son's bedroom for one of them (I guess other people could buy separated beds if they do not have the empty rooms). Again, I cannot say how common it can be.

Comment: @curious_cat Let me rephrase: Once again, you seem to assume there was a shift from two bedrooms per couple to one bedroom. Unless you are specifically talking about the upper upper class (in which case you should specify), this assumption is wrong. The reality is rather a shift in the other direction, it's probably more common than ever *today* to have separate rooms, because more people can afford it. Such a thing as more separate bedrooms wasn't affordable for 99.9% of the people in the 1800s.

Comment: @SJuan76 Thank you for that insight. That is indeed interesting to know. I did not know that.

Comment: Anecdote from personal history: my grandparents, born in 1900-1910 decade, slept in separate beds their entire lives. (Naturalized US Citizens)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Movies portray people as having separate beds to get around [strict censorship laws](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080710155903AAKKrvC) which were derived from old [religious traditions](http://www.jewishjournal.com/bloggish/item/the_tradition_of_sleeping_in_separate_beds_in_jewish_marriages).

In reality, there have been many such [movements](http://www.strangehistory.net/2013/10/17/why-do-married-couples-sleep-in-the-same-bed/) for and against sleeping together, and it appears to have gone in and out of style through the ages.

Comment: this pretty much sums it up. +1

Comment: I don't think the censorship argument applies because I've seen plenty of modern films that depict the older eras with seperate rooms for him & her. Surely a movie made post 1960 was free from censors so conservative?

Comment: @curious_cat a movie post 1960 would try to look familiar to viewers. If all previous films depicted Victorian couples sleeping in different bedrooms, film viewers would have expected that; what's more, possibly most script writers would not know better how life was than from other films (and even if the script writer knew, he was in the show business, not the documentary business).

Comment: @SJuan76 this is very sad, but unfortunately I think it's also correct :(

Comment: It actually turned out that the Victorians were incredibly liberal sexually. We're really great at revising history to fit misconceptions.

Comment: @Axelrod they were, but they were also rather private about it. So they'd likely have separate rooms for appearances, with maybe one of them being rarely used for example. A lot of the sexual imagery of the era is highly allegorical, lots of (to us) obscure references that the people of the era would understand very well. My former English teacher made a study of sexual imagery in Shakespeare (ok, different era maybe, but similar) which cast a completely new light on the fights in some of his plays...

Answer (score 3):

The question is different now and requires a new answer.
Have you read Jack London's [The People of the Abyss?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_People_of_the_Abyss) Yes, commoners in England slept in one bedroom, and many of them lived in one room, too.

Comment: Gangnus, please don't adopt Tyler's predilection: this is so much your opinion, unless you can back it up with sources. Please do so.

Comment: The whole question is taking on the presumption that some country the author is from is a whole world. I need not to support by references the fact of existence of the outer world. If you need them, it is the problem of your strange community. Look any document film about how usual people live in Africa, in China, in India, in Japan. Or better try to live at least a pair of years there. But the time spent in an european hotel can not be taken into account!

Comment: @CGCampbell https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FQtZ_aKGcdI

Comment: and where do you get your idea that CC means when the majority of people sleep in separate rooms?

Comment: @jwenting He is asking when they left the separate bedrooms and started to sleep in shared.  But for that they had to sleep in separate ones sometimes. Somebody had seen too much pink films on "high society".

Comment: `And the Russian empire had HDP/person high above the average in the world` : No. Russia was by far the poorest European country before WWI.

Comment: @Gangnus There was no disrespected _to you_ intended by me or given. I was simply trying to let you know that our "strange little community ([history.se]) would **request** that any answerer back up his assertions with proof, or sources. While we do not (yet) allow requests for resources as the question itself, answers without sourcing is only one person's opinion.

Comment: @Gangnus I would also point out that the OP did provide a scope to the question so as to be something less than the entire world.

Comment: @Gangnus he asked when people started doing it, not when the majority of people were/are doing it... Big difference.

Comment: @jwenting I see. Now the question is absolutely different. And has sense. But my answer is correct for the old content. So, I can only add info to the current.